# How to avoid triple colon (:::) when writing an S3 method?

Tags: r, class, methods, plot

I'm writing a package and I have a function that returns a `data.frame` with a class `myclass`. It is important to keep it as a data.frame, so I'm adding the new class to the object (the codes below do not make much sense of course, but it is merely for illustration):

```
foo <-  function(x) {
  df <- data.frame(a = x, b = "b", c = 1)
  class(df) <- append(class(df), "myclass")
  return(df)
}

test <- foo(1:3)
```

Now, I would like to create a S3 method for this class as:

```
plot.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
  plot(a~b, data = test)
}
```

The problem is that since `test` is a `data.frame`, `plot(test)` will call the unexported function `plot.data.frame` from the package `graphics`.

I tried to get around this by defining another (unexported) function as:

```
plot.data.frame <-  function(x, ...){
  if ("myclass" %in% class(x)) plot.myclass(x, ...)
  else graphics:::plot.data.frame(x, ...)
}
```

which works fine, but `devtools::check()` gives me a warning, and indeed the documentation of `:::` says that

> It is typically a design mistake to use ::: in your code since the
>   corresponding object has probably been kept internal for a good
>   reason. Consider contacting the package maintainer if you feel the
>   need to access the object for anything but mere inspection.

What is the preferred way to solve that problem?

I can of course (i) get rid of the `data.frame` class, but as I said, I'd prefer to keep it (ii) simply copy the existing code of `plot.data.frame` into the `else` statement of the last function, or (iii) simply overwriting the original `plot.data.frame` with loosing the original functionality (plotting data frames) - none of which seems to be any more elegant than what I came up with, but I'm sure there is a better solution.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess normal practice is to put your class first, not last, so `c("myclass", class(x))` or `append(class(x), "myclass", 0)`..? Also, fyi, there's `inherits` so you don't have to do `%in% class(x)`

Comment: This is covered in the details section of ?UseMethod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want your `'myclass'` to come *before* the `'data.frame'` class in the class of the object. That way dispatch will look for `<generic>.myclass` first and only look for `<generic>.data.frame` if it can't find a method for the generic for class `'myclass'`.

To achieve this you can simply modify this one line

```
class(df) <- append(class(df), "myclass")
```

to read

```
class(df) <- append(class(df), "myclass", after = 0)
```

but it's just as easy to use

```
class(df) <- c('myclass', class(df))
```

for the latter and it's pretty explicit, whereas the `append()` is really backwards as you need *prepend* the class.

As for the more general problem, there isn't a way to import or use a non-exported method or function in another package's namespace without generating all manner of warnings when checking the package. It is assumed that you shouldn't be calling a non-exported function directly (because that function is not intended for user usage) and that any attempt to do so is a problem for packaged code.